# Broken link when adding discussion board to page through listviewwebpart

Tags: list, web-part, discussion-board

**Background:**

I have a discussion board in SharePoint where users will dump emails through an Outlook connection.  Then they will associate the discussion board post with a particular contact.  When viewing the display form for a contact I want them to be able to see the emails (discussion board posts) for that contact at the bottom of the page.  I've added the list of emails at the bottom of the display form and connected it to the form web part so that it only shows emails for that contact.

**Problem:**

The list of emails shows up correctly but the link to view the flat view of the post is incorrect.  Instead of linking to the page with the flat view it links back to the display form that I am already on.  When I click on the link I get an exception page because it combines the correct query string with an incorrect page target.  The exception is an "Invalid Field Name" exception referring to field "Parent Folder Id" with guid a9ec25bf-5a22-4658-bd19-484e52efbe1a.

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid field name. {a9ec25bf-5a22-4658-bd19-484e52efbe1a}  
  /sites/BusinessDevelopment/Lists/BD  Contact   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldById(Guid fieldId, Boolean bThrowException)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormRowProviderInterface.FireMainIfAppropriate()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart.PartCommunicationMain()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.Communication.PartCommunicationPhase.Invoke()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ActivateV2Connections()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ActivateV2ConnectionsAndSharePointDataFetch()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ActivateConnections()    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.OnPageLoadComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)    
 at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a workaround by creating a new column to copy what the "Subject (with link to item)" column does.  The new column is called "Link Url" and is a hyperlink column type.  I have a workflow that updates this column when a discussion board post is updated or created.  It sets the value of "Link Url" to:

```
[%Current Item: Encoded Absolute Url%], [%Current Item:Subject%]
```

Then I just use the "Link Url" column in my list view instead of the "Subject (with link to item)" column.